# SSH problem using Netbeans and Git

Tags: git, netbeans, ssh

I have looked at the other posts from the other folks regarding this issue but I still have problems getting ssh to work with netbeans & git on windows 7. I am new to git so I am sure I am missing something somewhere.

I have done `init git` on my Ubuntu server. I have also set a `%HOME%` under the "user variables for username" in system properties->advanced->environment variables and created a `.ssh` folder in the path that I defined for `%HOME%`. Now where so I get the key files? I copied them from the Ubuntu server to there but when I am trying to connect by netbean using ssh it still says

> ssh://user@200.200.200.111/git: reject HostKey: 200.200.200.111

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with NetBeans 7.0.1.

Bug 199263 - Cannot connect to remote repositories with just ssh public/private keys
Here is the link to their bug database:

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199263

Looks like it has been fixed for the next release (7.1). I tried it and it worked for me. Here is where I got the latest dev build:

http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

Remember, dev builds may have some stability problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've no Windows nor Netbeans at hand here, but that message looks like the 200.200.200.111 host is not in the `known_hosts` file. Try doing `ssh 200.200.200.111` from the console, it should ask if you trust the hosts' fingerprint, answer yes and it will be stored in `known_hosts` file.

Comment: I am using putty to connect to that host and I am sure I have trusted the host at some point but I still have the problem.

Comment: Putty has its own known hosts registry, separate from ssh git is using.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure what ssh is used by Netbeans' git implementation. Not Putty though, I guess.